# How to create a date column with conditional format in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, strftime

I hope you can help me out with this one, which I think it's easy but I just can't manage to solve it.  I have a Dataframe with a datetime zone column as string and a country column. Date values for USA are in "%y-%d-%m" format and for the rest of the world is  "%y-%m-%d". What I want to do is to create another column with the same date format. Thing is that i have to use one format for USA and another one for the rest of the world, How can I Solve this?

```
data={"datetime":["2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST","2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST","2020-10-02 8:02:55 PM PST"],"country":["USA","USA","FRANCE"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df["Month"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["date"]).month
df["Year"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["date"]).year
df
```

Here's the DataFrame I Get (i couldnt paste it with the DT Format, how do you do that, btw?). Thing is that for France it uses 2 as the month value. I tried to use python pd.series.dt.strftime but i can't manage to use it with the country coundition so I can use one format for usa and another one for the rest of the countries.

```
                    datetime country                date  Month  Year
0  2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST     USA 2020-02-10 20:02:55      2  2020
1  2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST     USA 2020-02-10 20:02:55      2  2020
2  2020-10-02 8:02:55 PM PST  FRANCE 2020-10-02 20:02:55     10  2020
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: To "how do you do that": (1) Select the pasted code that you'd like to make it a code block and press the `{}` button on the top of the editor. (2) enclose the section with triple backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify if the day comes first with the `dayfirst` keyword. The challenge here seems to be parsing `PST` correctly to time zone `US/Pacific`. You can do that with a mapping dict - however, `pd.to_datetime` doesn't support that (yet, v1.1.3) so you'll have to use `dateutil` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil 

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST", "2020-02-10 8:02:55 PM PST", "2020-10-02 8:02:55 PM PST"],
                   "country": ["USA", "USA", "FRANCE"]})

# add column that specifies day first:
df['dayfirst'] = df['country'] == "FRANCE"

# create a mapping dict, mapping strings to time zones. add more if needed (e.g. PDT).
tzinfos = {'PST': dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Pacific')}

# create a function to parse the datetime strings
# this is not strictly needed but seems appropriate in terms of readability
def custom_parse_date(r):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(r['datetime'], dayfirst=r['dayfirst'], tzinfos=tzinfos)

df['parsed_dt'] = df.apply(lambda r: custom_parse_date(r), axis=1) 

# df['parsed_dt']
# 0   2020-02-10 20:02:55-08:00
# 1   2020-02-10 20:02:55-08:00
# 2   2020-02-10 20:02:55-08:00
# Name: parsed_dt, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzfile('US/Pacific')]
```